# Get Branch commit version in gitlab ci

Tags: github, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a requirement to zip the artifacts folder and name it with last commit version name in gitlab-ci.yml file  to the below exisiting code

```
build-docker:
  stage: build
  before_script:
   - git clean -xfdf
  tags:
  - docker-linux
  image: node
  script: 
    - echo "Start building App"
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - npm run test
    - echo "Build successfully!"
    - if [ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" ]; then node ./sonarqube-scanner.js --serverUrl $SONAR_URL --token $SONAR_PAT --projectName 'blk-support-portal' --sources 'src'; fi;
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/

build-docker:
  stage: build
  before_script:
   - git clean -xfdf
  tags:
  - docker-linux
  image: node
  script: 
    - echo "Start building App"
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - npm run test
    - echo "Build successfully!"
    - if [ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" ]; then node ./sonarqube-scanner.js --serverUrl $SONAR_URL --token $SONAR_PAT --projectName 'blk-support-portal' --sources 'src'; fi;
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/
```

Thanks,
Rohith

Comment: You can get the current commit SHA with the Predefined Variable `CI_COMMIT_SHA`.

Comment: Corect but i want version number

Comment: There is no version number in git, unless you're talking about a `tag` that already exists. If the current pipeline is being run for a tag, you can get the tag name with `CI_COMMIT_TAG`, but beware, that variable only exists for Tag pipelines. With a regular Push pipeline that variable will be empty `''`.